# Function to free pointers not working

Tags: c, pointers, free

I'm learning C and trying to figure out an elegant way to free my pointers at the end of the execution.

After hours debugging and experimenting different things with the following code, I couldn't manage to figure out what I was doing wrong:

```
int ClosePointers(char *pointersToClose[], int arraySize) {
    int index;
    for(index = 0; index < arraySize; index++) {
        char *pointer = pointersToClose[index];
        free(pointer);
    }
    return (0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *pointersToClose[4];
  char *pointer1;
  char *pointer2;
  char *pointer3;
  char *pointer4;

  pointersToClose[0] = pointer1;
  pointersToClose[1] = pointer2;
  pointersToClose[2] = pointer3;
  pointersToClose[3] = pointer4;

  pointer1 = malloc(10);
  pointer2 = malloc(10);
  pointer3 = malloc(10);
  pointer4 = malloc(10);

  /*some important code here using the pointers*/

  ClosePointers(pointersToClose, 4);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:
*** glibc detected *** /home/workspace/Debug/Test-POC: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000038ce7b9850 ***

Could you help me out pointing what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Define what you mean by "closing". It highly depends on what the pointer is pointing to

Comment: You cannot "close" pointers.

Comment: What I meant is free, not close.
I come from another language and sometimes I mix concepts.

Comment: @Olaf :). I updated that to "free". Probably OP is not native English speaker.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, I'm not native English speaker, but the real issue here was mixing concepts. I come from 11 years of Java development and I have 2 days of C development... so, I guess you can imagine the hell that's going on inside my head.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: This is also not about freeing pointer either. All you can do is free the object it **points to**. This is a major difference.

Comment: @Olaf Right sir. In title markdowns don't work. I try to read it as _Function calling `free()` on pointers not working_. Though, I agree, _not working_ is not a very good problem statement, either.

Comment: Note that although it is not wrong to manually free allocated memory at the end of a program's execution, it is also not especially useful, because the memory will be returned to the OS anyway when the process exits.  On the whole, however, it's a good to establish a practice of freeing allocated memory when you no longer need it, especially as a learner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `free` on those pointers, but you never allocate any memory to them with `malloc`.  In fact, the pointers you are trying to `free` are uninitialized, so they could contain anything.

When you set the values of `pointersToClose`, you're assigning the *current* value of `pointer1`, `pointer2`, etc., not whatever value they may contain when "some important code here using the pointers" runs.

Passing a pointer value to `free` that was not returned by `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc` results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to do this, try putting the *address* of each of the pointers in question in your array.

```
int ClosePointers(char **pointersToClose[], int arraySize) {
    int index;
    for(index = 0; index < arraySize; index++) {
        char **pointer = pointersToClose[index];
        free(*pointer);
    }
    return (0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char **pointersToClose[4];
  char *pointer1;
  char *pointer2;
  char *pointer3;
  char *pointer4;

  pointersToClose[0] = &pointer1;
  pointersToClose[1] = &pointer2;
  pointersToClose[2] = &pointer3;
  pointersToClose[3] = &pointer4;

  /*some important code here using the pointers*/

  ClosePointers(pointersToClose, 4);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey @dbush , I was allocating with malloc the pointers but I forgot to copy/paste them into the question... they are there now... but I tried your code and it finally compiled and ran as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: Most of the `char`s should be `void`, to be more general.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you help me out pointing what I'm doing wrong?

You should use `free()` only on pointers that you allocated on the heap using the `malloc()` function.

What happens, is that within the heap (a reserved memory space), the length you gave as parameter to the `malloc()` function is allocated for your use, and it returns the address to the first word of that memory space so it can be assigned to a pointer.

When you use `free()`, it's deallocating that memory space so it can be reused.

Here, you create pointers variables that points to nothing (actually they point to a random value). So what's happening when you call `free()` on those variables is that you try to deallocate some random memory space that is not within the managed space, called the heap. As those addresses are unlikely to be allocated by `malloc()`, the `free()` function cannot know what to do with it, and therefore will return an error!

Read on about [what are the stack and the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80113/1290438) to better understand what those are. Also, read the [C programming language book by Kernighan and Ritchie](https://hassanolity.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf) where it's all well explained.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using malloc... forgot to add it to the code...... searching for my original code to get the malloc lines.

Comment: `Here you're closing pointers allocated on the stack`..umm..can you elaborate please?

Comment: I detailed, sorry for the shortcut in the thinking

Answer (score 0):

In your code. `pointer1` is unitialized. It points to *invalid* memory. Passing that to `free()` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3, (emphasis mine)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. **Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

You need to either

- set that to `NULL` (`null-pointer` constant)
- use `malloc()` or family to allocate `free`-able memory first.

*That said, `pointer2`, `pointer3` and `pointer4` are undeclared in your code but probably that's a typo, so we can overlook it.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to free a pointer you must first have allocate memmory for it. You are going to free pointers that are never allocated. Try the following code to understnd what you did wrong

```
int AllocatePointers(char *pointersToClose[], int arraySize) {
  int index;
  for(index = 0; index < arraySize; index++) {
     pointersToClose[index] = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
  }
  return (0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *pointersToClose[4];
  char *pointer1;
  char *pointer2;
  char *pointer3;
  char *pointer4;

  pointersToClose[0] = pointer1;
  pointersToClose[1] = pointer2;
  pointersToClose[2] = pointer3;
  pointersToClose[3] = pointer4;

  AllocatePointers(pointersToClose, 4);

  /*some important code here using the pointers*/

  ClosePointers(pointersToClose, 4);

  return 0;
}
```